# Why won't my XPages replicate?

Tags: xpages, replication, lotus-domino, database-replication

Have a database where I created some XPages. I wanted to move to another server for testing, so I made a replica of the database in the usual way.  Then I went to the test server and created some new XPages. But now they don't replicate back to the original server.

Other documents replicate, such as regular documents and new Forms and Views I created, but not the XPages. There are no replication settings to prohibit design replication, no templates are involved, and both servers are Manager either explicitly or through `LocalDomainServers`. Any suggestions?

Comment: Try to do a replication manually from your client. And see if the replication works then.

Comment: Standard troubleshooting procedure: check all settings and logs. I suspect it is security issue, but can be anything. I don't think it is XPages problem.